# How to make update in Django webservice made in python on windows

Tags: django, windows, wordpress, web-services, python-2.7

I have installed `Python 27` successfully.

And with respect to project requirement i have also installed following packages.

```
Django==1.4.3

MySQL-python==1.2.4

PIL==1.1.7

South==0.7.6

argparse==1.2.1

distribute==0.6.28

django-appconf==0.6

django-imagekit==2.0.2

pytz==2012j

six==1.2.0

wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Now the problem is, i dont know how to make this run, or visible in python.

Can anybody please help me, to get out from this.

I have to change few webservices and also want to add some functionality.

This webservices are attached with wordpress website.

So, please help me to configure whole this project on local (Windows PC).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go for the **[Touch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/)** Command of Django for this issue,

I think it will make helpful to you.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i have solve this, find below instruction for users who have same queries:

```
Restarting the Spawned Server

If you change any Python code on your site, you’ll need to tell FastCGI the code has changed. But there’s no need to restart Apache in this case. Rather, just reupload mysite.fcgi – or edit the file – so that the timestamp on the file changes. When Apache sees the file has been updated, it will restart your Django application for you.

If you have access to a command shell on a Unix system, you can accomplish this easily by using the touch command:
```

**touch mysite.fcgi**

For more information:
http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12.html

Thanks